# How to get specific elements fro JSON using python?

Tags: python, json

I'm getting a json file from a url:

```
url= "something"
json_url = urlopen(url)
data = json.loads(json_url.read())
```

The json file:

```
 data = [[{"traceId": "07a107a461fbbe3f", "localEndpoint": {"serviceName":   "name_1"}, "tags": { "http.method": "GET"}, "shared": true}, 
    {"traceId": "07a107a461fbbe3f", "localEndpoint": 
      {"serviceName": "name_2"}}], [{"traceId": "07a107a461fbbe3f", "localEndpoint": {"serviceName":  "name_1"}, "tags": { "http.method": "GET"}, "shared": true}, 
    {"traceId": "07a107a461fbbe3f", "localEndpoint": 
      {"serviceName": "name_2"}}], [{"traceId": "07a107a461fbbe3f", "localEndpoint": {"serviceName":  "name_1"}, "tags": { "http.method": "GET"}, "shared": true}, 
    {"traceId": "07a107a461fbbe3f", "localEndpoint": 
      {"serviceName": "name_2"}}]]
```

If I try to get

```
 data["serviceName"] or 
 data["http.method"] but I'm getting an error...
```

I would like to access every value separately.
This also doesn't work:

```
 data[0]['localEndpoint']['serviceName']
```

Could someone help?

Comment: what error are you getting?

Comment: `data[0][0]['localEndpoint']['serviceName']`

Comment: I'm getting this: 'TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str'

Comment: yes, data is list. Try `type(data)`. You have to index list by integers

Comment: I sure hope your JSON does not really start with the string `data = `.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting a list. Try this :

data[0][0]["localEndpoint"]["serviceName"]